# Devtools detector, antibugging

Tags: javascript, detection, devtools

I'm not going to ask how we can block debugging tools or block the inspect element. I want to implement some javascript function as soon as user tries to open devtools as **SoundCloud** website did.

Comment: Do you need `console.info('Some text')`?

Answer (score 0):

After some researching [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/) site I found this line of code, may be it will help you. They just use `console.info` at the start:

```js
 null != (d = window.console) && d.info && window.console.info('You like to look under the hood? Why not help us build the engine? https://soundcloud.com/jobs');
```

P.S. At the moment this line of code you can find in [this file](https://a-v2.sndcdn.com/assets/49-2c7cec0a.js)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help but this is for the Windows Shortcut.

```
window.oncontextmenu = function () {
return false;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
var key = event.key || event.keyCode;

if (key == 123) {
    return false;
} else if ((event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && key == 73) || (event.ctrlKey 
&& event.shiftKey && key == 74)) {
    return false;
 }
}, false);
```